# What is the fastest way to read 10 GB file from the disk?

Tags: perl, io, mmap, performance

We need to read and count different types of messages/run
some statistics on a 10 GB text file, e.g a [FIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange) engine
log. We use Linux, 32-bit, 4 CPUs, Intel, coding in Perl but
the language doesn't really matter.

I have found some interesting tips in Tim Bray's 
[WideFinder project](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/09/20/Wide-Finder). However, we've found that using memory mapping
is inherently limited by the 32 bit architecture.

We tried using multiple processes, which seems to work
faster if we process the file in parallel using 4 processes
on 4 CPUs. Adding multi-threading slows it down, maybe
because of the cost of context switching. We tried changing
the size of thread pool, but that is still slower than
simple multi-process version.

The memory mapping part is not very stable, sometimes it
takes 80 sec and sometimes 7 sec on a 2 GB file, maybe from
page faults or something related to virtual memory usage.
Anyway, Mmap cannot scale beyond 4 GB on a 32 bit
architecture.

We tried Perl's [IPC::Mmap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IPC-Mmap) and [Sys::Mmap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Sys::Mmap). Looked
into Map-Reduce as well, but the problem is really I/O
bound, the processing itself is sufficiently fast.

So we decided to try optimize the basic I/O by tuning
buffering size, type, etc.

Can anyone who is aware of an existing project where this
problem was efficiently solved in any language/platform
point to a useful link or suggest a direction?

Comment: What is the raw performance on a single cpu for 2G?  You probably need to determine if the I/O is the issue or the CPU computations.

Comment: If you're really disk (IO) bound, then the best approach is probably to buy faster disks, more disks (in RAID0, RAID5, RAID10, etc.) or a 64-bit machine with enough memory to store the file on a RAM disk. Any reasonable single disk should be able to pull 50MB/sec; multiple fast disks should be able to push you to at least 300MB/sec.

Comment: I'd recommend you not to use Sys::Mmap but File-Map (for reasons that are stated in the latter's documentation). In any case you probably don't want to use IPC::Mmap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the time you will be I/O bound not CPU bound, thus just read this file through normal Perl I/O and process it in single thread. Unless you prove that you can do more I/O than your single CPU work, don't waste your time with anything more. Anyway, you should ask: Why on Earth is this in one huge file? Why on Earth don't they split it in a reasonable way when they generate it? It would be magnitude more worth work. Then you can put it in separate I/O channels and use more CPU's (if you don't use some sort of RAID 0 or [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) or ...).

Measure, don't assume. Don't forget to flush caches before each test. Remember that serialized I/O is a magnitude faster than random.

Answer (score 4):

This all depends on what kind of preprocessing you can do and and when. 
On some of systems we have, we gzip such large text files, reducing them to 1/5 to 1/7 of their original size. Part of what makes this possible is we don't need to process these files
until hours after they're created, and at creation time we don't really have any other load on the machines.

Processing them is done more or less in the fashion of zcat thosefiles | ourprocessing.(well it's done over unix sockets though with a custom made zcat). It trades cpu time for disk i/o time, and for our system that has been *well* worth it. There's ofcourse a lot of variables that can make this a very poor design for a particular system.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you've already read this forum thread, but if not:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=512221

It describes using Perl to do it line-by-line, and the users seem to think Perl is quite capable of it.

Oh, is it possible to process the file from a RAID array?  If you have several mirrored disks, then the read speed can be improved.  Competition for disk resources may be what makes your multiple-threads attempt not work.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

I wish I knew more about the content of your file, but not knowing other than that it is text, this sounds like an excellent MapReduce kind of problem.

PS, the fastest read of any file is a linear read. `cat file > /dev/null` should be the speed that the file can be read.

Comment: Indeed; my colleague working on a similar problem was using the timing from cat to track down other issues in file read speeds. NFS was an awful time suck. :(

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of streaming the file and filtering out to a secondary file any interesting results? (Repeat until you have a manageble size file).

Answer (score 2):

Parse the file once, reading line by line. Put the results in a table in a decent database. Run as many queries as you wish. Feed the beast regularly with new incoming data.

Realize that manipulating a 10 Gb file, transferring it across the (even if local) network, exploring complicated solutions etc all take time.

Comment: Feed database and run queries can take magnitude more time than do all processing in perl. (It's from mine experience even you use bulk load and MySQL which is one of fastest approaches what you can use.)

Comment: Once you have the data in a *decent* database, you can run as many queries as you want (even those you did not know you may have wanted to run) with little extra cost.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said platform and language doesn't matter...

If you want a stable performance that is as fast as the source medium allows for, the only way I am aware that this can be done on Windows is by overlapped non-OS-buffered aligned sequential reads. You can probably get to some GB/s with two or three buffers, beyond that, at some point you need a ring buffer (one writer, 1+ readers) to avoid any copying. The exact implementation depends on the driver/APIs. If there's any memory copying going on the thread (both in kernel and usermode) dealing with the IO, obviously the larger buffer is to copy, the more time is wasted on that rather than doing the IO. So the optimal buffer size depends on the firmware and driver. On windows good values to try are multiples of 32 KB for disk IO. Windows file buffering, memory mapping and all that stuff adds overhead. Only good if doing either (or both) multiple reads of same data in random access manner. So for reading a large file sequentially a single time, you don't want the OS to buffer anything or do any memcpy's. If using C# there's also penalties for calling into the OS due to marshaling, so the interop code may need bit of optimization unless you use C++/CLI.

Some people prefer throwing hardware at problems but if you have more time than money, in some scenarios it's possible to optimize things to perform 100-1000x better on a single consumer level computer than a 1000 enterprise priced computers. The reason is that if the processing is also latency sensitive, going beyond using two cores is probably adding latency. This is why drivers can push gigabytes/s while enterprise software is ends stuck at megabytes/s by the time it's all done. Whatever reporting, business logic and such the enterprise software do can probably also be done at gigabytes/s on two core consumer CPU, if written like you were back in the 80's writing a game. The most famous example I've heard of approaching their entire business logic in this manner is the LMAX forex exchange, which published some of their ring buffer based code, which was said to be inspired by network card drivers.

Forgetting all the theory, if you are happy with < 1 GB/s, one possible starting point on Windows I've found is looking at readfile source from winimage, unless you want to dig into sdk/driver samples. It may need some source code fixes to calculate perf correctly at SSD speeds. Experiment with buffer sizes also.
The switches /h multi-threaded and /o overlapped (completion port) IO with optimal buffer size (try 32,64,128 KB etc) using no windows file buffering in my experience give best perf when reading from SSD (cold data) while simultaneously processing (use the /a for Adler processing as otherwise it's too CPU-bound).

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall a project in which we were reading big files, Our implementation used multithreading - basically n * worker_threads were starting at incrementing offsets of the file (0, chunk_size, 2xchunk_size, 3x chunk_size ... n-1x chunk_size) and was reading smaller chunks of information. I can't exactly recall our reasoning for this as someone else was desining the whole thing - the workers weren't the only thing to it, but that's roughly how we did it.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Basically need to "Divide and conquer", if you have a network of computers, then copy the 10G file to as many client PCs as possible, get each client PC to read an offset of the file. For added bonus, get EACH pc to implement multi threading in addition to distributed reading.

Comment: "the problem is really IO bound" <--- good luck copying the file to a machine faster than the disks can read it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a co-worker who sped up his FIX reading by going to 64-bit Linux. If it's something worthwhile, drop a little cash to get some fancier hardware.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, but what's wrong with the read() command in C?  Usually has a 2GB limit,
so just call it 5 times in sequence.  That should be fairly fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you are I/O bound and your file is on a single disk, then there isn't much to do.  A straightforward single-threaded linear scan across the whole file is the fastest way to get the data off of the disk.  Using large buffer sizes might help a bit.

If you can convince the writer of the file to stripe it across multiple disks / machines, then you could think about multithreading the reader (one thread per read head, each thread reading the data from a single stripe).

Answer (score 0):

Its not stated in the problem that sequence matters really or not. So,
divide the file into equal parts say 1GB each, and since you are using multiple CPUs, then multiple threads wont be a problem, so read each file using separate thread, and use RAM of capacity > 10 GB, then all your contents would be stored in RAM read by multiple threads.